I don't have LC_ADD ="en_US.UTF-8"
I followed this video, How to Correctly Install ROS2 Jazzy Jalisco in Linux Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble) - ROS2 Tutorial, and I see I don't have lc_all. So I have some problems when I run sudo apt update, and I don't know how to fix them.
hungdeptrai@hungdeptrai-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-2:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install locales
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease               
Ign:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu humble InRelease                      
Err:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu humble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:3402:200:227::2 80]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu humble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


This question is similar to: What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
